# Do Juniper switches support vtp?

Tags: cisco, juniper, networking

We have a mostly Cisco network, though for our access layer we usually deploy Juniper Virtual Chassis switches. To replicate this, we are interested in deploying a few juniper switches in our product development lab. The downside is we have well over a hundred vlans in that lab.

Is there any support for VTP? Did they license it for cisco? Or will I have to grab a copy of the vlan database off of one our other switches and implement it manually on the juniper switches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VTP is proprietary to Cisco.

Juniper implements something similar with GVRP and MVRP (both industry standard protocols).

You'll need to look into both of these protocols to determine exactly what you need and how to deploy them though.  It's not something that is a quick "everyone can just run this CLI command" thing for these to function properly.

Comment: And a side note... VTP (and similar vendor-agnostic protocols) are an easy way to bite yourself. Script it and do it with full control, vs the 'every vlan everywhere' mentatlity VTP forces on you.